# why process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST will be undefined in test environment? even though I have run the emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mocha.js

I am using

- Node 14
- firebase functions-test: 0.2.3
- firebase-admin: 9.6.0
- firebase-functions: 3.13.2
- firebase tools: 9.10.0
- mocha: 8.3.2,
- ts-node: 9.1.1

if I run `firebase emulators:start`

then I will expect `process.env` will have properties like

```
"FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR": "true",
"FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST": "localhost:8080"
```

now I need to create testing for my cloud function using mocha, I will test it using Firestore and functions emulator, I give my file name `events_cron_job.test.ts`

after I run the simulator, I try to console log those values and I got undefined like this

[image]

I expect

```
console.log(process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR)  // will be "true"
console.log(process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST) // will be "localhost:8080"
```

I think this is only happen in test environment ( I am using mocha ), I have regular http triggers and it works as expected

before running the emulator, I try to execute this on terminal

```
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:8080"
export FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR="true"
```

and then execute `firebase emulators:start` , but the result will be the same, I still get undefined for those values

because those values are undefined, then if my laptop is disconnected from the internet, then this testing will not run ( i.e it will only access the data in production server, not the emulator! ), I expect the test will still run even if there is no internet connection since I use emulator.

I run the mocha test using

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/cloud_function_tests --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit
```

Comment: Have you tried running the test like it what was described in [this gitbub issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/94#issuecomment-533066616)

Comment: @RafaelLemos yup, thats the solution, I finally find it after 4 days. thanks Rafael !

Comment: Great, I will make this into an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in this [Github issue comment](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/94#issuecomment-533066616), in order to run tests with the Firebase emulator you should use the following command to trigger it:

```
firebase emulators:exec "npm test"
```

As this is how tests where intended to be executed by the Firebase Team using the emulator.